# Problem with the header at using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, logos

I'm new in LaTeX and I have a problem creating my header at using fancyhdr package. When I include it, the text overlaps in the upper part of the header, and I've tried to fix with the command `\setlength\headheight{3cm}`. But the text of the rest of the pages comes out lower than on this page and the format of the document is ruined. Sorry for my english, I am not an english speaker and I hope to you understand me.  I also include my code and the result.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noindentfirst]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font={small},labelfont={bf,small},
   justification=centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage[paperwidth=195mm,paperheight=265mm,twoside,
inner=2.2cm,outer=2.2cm,top=2.25cm,bottom=2.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,
   citecolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength\headheight{3cm}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.075\textwidth]{logos/Logo_EPN} \\ \normalsize Year 2019}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\Large\textbf{\textsc{Escuela Politécnica Nacional}}\\ \large \textbf{\textsc{Math 1 $\star$ Summary}}\\ \large\textsc{Functions}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=0.075\textwidth]{logos/Buho_EPN} \\ \normalsize Autor's Name}  


\section{Section One}
\blindtext
\medskip
\blindtext
\medskip
\blindtext
\medskip
\section{two}
\blindtext
\medskip
\blindtext
\medskip
\blindtext
\medskip
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please refer to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage for the creation of a title. Using `fancyhdr` is completely the wrong tool.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Johannes_B that you should consider other forms of Title Creation. However, you could modify the `headheight` only for the style you are using for the first page.

*Snippet*

```
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
%   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.075\textwidth]{logos/Logo_EPN} \\ \normalsize Year 2019}
    \fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\Large\textbf{\textsc{Escuela Politécnica Nacional}}\\ \large \textbf{\textsc{Math 1 $\star$ Summary}}\\ \large\textsc{Functions}}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=0.075\textwidth]{logos/Buho_EPN} \\ \normalsize Autor's Name}  
    \setlength\headheight{3cm}
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}
```

*Example*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noindentfirst]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font={small},labelfont={bf,small},
   justification=centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage[paperwidth=195mm,paperheight=265mm,twoside,
inner=2.2cm,outer=2.2cm,top=2.25cm,bottom=2.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,
   citecolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
%   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.075\textwidth]{logos/Logo_EPN} \\ \normalsize Year 2019}
    \fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\Large\textbf{\textsc{Escuela Politécnica Nacional}}\\ \large \textbf{\textsc{Math 1 $\star$ Summary}}\\ \large\textsc{Functions}}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=0.075\textwidth]{logos/Buho_EPN} \\ \normalsize Autor's Name}  
    \setlength\headheight{3cm}
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}

\section{Section One}
\Blindtext
\section{two}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```